# Override a plugin to restore movement key?

Tags: cursor-movement, plugin-system, movement

I'm using the [pencil](https://github.com/reedes/vim-pencil) plugin which remaps the jk movement buttons to go up/down by row (text is soft wrapped) rather than line, which is usually helpful. But at times I want to have the normal behavior so that I can quickly move from one line to another.

How can I restore the remapped keys (j and k) temporarily so I can toggle the pencil behavior on and off? Or is there another way of doing this?

I can't toggle pencil itself, because for one reason or another (probably buginess) it messes up the formatting.

My actual need is to go from one *paragraph* to another (the beginning would be fine). But I don't mean a *vim paragraph* that is set off by blank lines. My text document has paragraphs set off by **indentation** (so each paragraph is effectively one *vim line*). So if there's another way besides using the vim key to move from one paragraph to another. That would work for me. I can't use the { key because it jumps to blank lines.

Comment: Can you show some examples with an [edit]? I'm having a hard time visualizing—my questions would be, (1) what are `j` and `k` mapped too? (2) What is some text that you would consider "paragraphs set off by indentation," and where would you like to jump to? (AFAIK there is no simple way to save/restore mappings, though there may be some more complex ways)

Comment: I have edited. Hope that helps. THank you!

Comment: Could you give some example text, please? (even just lorem-ipsum formatted the way you describe would be helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like [pencil (sometimes?) switches `j` with `gj` and `k` with `gk`](https://github.com/reedes/vim-pencil/blob/dad5a3626ab68039f2676c46e7a1635e0669cc63/autoload/pencil.vim#L414), so you could use `gj` and `gk` as substitutes.

I'm not sure why toggling pencil would mess up the formatting (perhaps it only changes how the text is displayed, or perhaps they like to automatically reflow text), but you might be able to toggle modes (hard and soft wrap) to get other mappings back.

Comment: Wow, thanks so much! I missed that. Maybe it wasn't documented.

Comment: @aris haha probably the latter